# Does psutil exist under python3 linux

Tags: linux, python-3.x, functional-programming

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "./shell-switcher.py", line 8, in

```
import psutil
```

ImportError: No module named psutil

Comment: `psutil` is third party, you will need to install it separately

Comment: thanks then i wanted to check if a process is in zombie state, i have the pid how can i do it ?